# Why does .svn folder appear in working copy created by pysvn?

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn, pysvn

I installed (Windows version) py27-pysvn-svn1811-1.7.10-1584. Because this also uses svn 1.8.11, I expected that I would not see the .svn folder in the working copy, in keeping with using TortoiseSVN 1.8.8, Build 25755 - 64 Bit, which uses Subversion 1.8.10. However, the .svn folder appears in the working copy created by pysvn, and my currently installed version of Tortoise asks me to use a prior version to access the working copy.

Have I misinterpreted the svn versions? Is there a different version of pysvn for Windows that I should install to have a working copy compatible with TortoiseSVN 1.8.8?

Comment: Take a closer look at pysvn name. It's for svn 1.7.10.

Comment: I guess that you need the first one in this table: http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html#download_Extension/Windows

Comment: BTW, SVN 1.8 has hidden `.svn` folder at the root of the working copy while SVN 1.7 and older versions contain the `.svn` directory at the root every folder in svn working copy.

Comment: bahrep, here is the line from the download section: py27-pysvn-svn1811-1.7.10-1584.exe 1.7.10 Python 2.7 SVN 1.8.11. This suggested to me that the SVN version was 1.8.11, and that the extension version was 1.7.10 (this number has the heading of Extension version in the table).

Comment: The choice of .svn and _svn is made by the code that checkd out the working copy. If that was pysvn then make sure that `pysvn.Client().get_adm_dir()` returns the _svn that you want and if required set it with `pysvn.Client().set_adm_dir('_svn')`