# Desktop was created as a SVN working copy. How to revert that

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

We're using SVN in our project and by mistake I ended making my Desktop as a working copy. And now, I'm unable remove it as a SVN working copy.

Here is a screenshot
[Desktop as SVN Working copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LHDR.png)

Can anybody help me with this?

I tried cleaup,revert and other options in TortoiseSVN but at no help.[options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aewlP.png)

Answer (score 2):

From version 1.8 the `.svn` folder is present only in the root directory of the working copy. I have not verify exactly the  version but I have found this info in an old comment of @bahrep:

> SVN 1.8 has hidden .svn folder at the root of the working copy while SVN 1.7 and older versions contain the .svn directory at the root every folder in svn working copy.

The comment is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893829/why-does-svn-folder-appear-in-working-copy-created-by-pysvn). The comment tells us that if you remove the hidden `.svn` folder from the `Desktop` folder, SVN can't manage it as a working copy.

So, to solve your problem, it is sufficient to **remove the hidden folder `.svn` from `Desktop` folder**.

Comment: Yep, this is all correct. And just FYI: single .svn director was released in SVN 1.8.0.